# Ordering dict objects based on multiple key values and comparison rules

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array of dict objects that I should have to order based on multiple rules.

This is how the sample dicts looks like:

```
dict1 = {'key1': '85', 'key2': '163', 'key3': '3'}
dict2 = {'key1': '3', 'key2': '23', 'key3': '1'}
dict3 = {'key1': '88', 'key2': '153', 'key3': '6'}
```

And these rules should be followed for the ordering:

```
key1 - the higher value is the better
key2 - the higher value is the better
key3 - the lower value is the better
```

So after the ordering my list should be like this:

```
dict_list = [dict1, dict3, dict2]

#dict1 is the first obj, because it has the biggest key1 + key2 value and the 2. lowest key3 value
```

`dict_list` objects by value (desired result):

```
 #   value name - high values (key1 + key2) - low values (key3)
 1.   dict1                  248                      3
 2.   dict3                  241                      6
 3.   dict2                  26                       1
```

From `key1` and `key2` I could create an absolute number for the comparison, but unfortunately I can't do it because `key3` would be still there and I can't use the same logic for it.

So my question: is it possible to define my own rules for the ordering? Is there any Python function for tasks like this?

Comment: So what do you do when you have {key1:2, key3:1} and {key1:1, key3:2}?

Comment: You can define your own ordering with a key function See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add key 1 and key 2 and subtract key 3 and order them on this number from high to low? If so, do this:

```
list_dicts = sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda x:int(x['key3'])-int(x['key2'])-int(x['key1']))
```

What this does is map your values to integers and subtract the values of key 1 and key 2 from the value of key 3, because it orders them from low to high. It will keep your original dictionaries, just in the wanted order.